# Changing the value of pointer causes unexpected behaviour c++

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main( ) 
{   


int *p; 
double *q; 
cout << p << " " << q << endl;
p++; 
q++; 
cout << p << " " << q << endl;
//*p = 5; // should be wrong!

}
```

This function prints

```
0x7ffe6c0591a0 0
0x7ffe6c0591a4 0x8
```

Why does p point to some randm address and q to zero? Also, when I uncomment the line *p=5, shouln't it throw an error? It still works fine:

```
code with line uncommented output 
0x7ffc909a2f70 0
0x7ffc909a2f74 0x8
```

What can explain this weird behaviour?

Comment: See: undefined behaviour. You have a lot of it.

Comment: This question basically boils to "Please define undefined behavior". Compile this code on different system or even by the different compiler and you will get different results. There is no need to reason with it, just don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When local (`auto`) variables of basic type (`int`, `double`, pointers to them, etc) are uninitialised, any operation that accesses their value yields undefined behaviour.

Printing a variable accesses its value, so both the statements with `cout << ...` give undefined behaviour.  Incrementing a variable also accesses its value (it is not possible to give the result of incrementing without accessing the previous value) so both the increment operators present undefined behaviour.  Derefererencing an unitialised pointer (as in `*p`) gives undefined behaviour, as does assigning a value to the result `*p = 5`.

So every statement you have shown after the definitions of `p` and `q` gives undefined behaviour.

Undefined behaviour means there are no constraints on what is permitted to happen - or, more simply, that anything can happen.   That allows any result from "appear to do nothing" to "crash" to "reformat your hard drive".

The particular output your are getting therefore doesn't really matter.   You may get completely different behavior when the code is built with a different compiler, or even during a different phase of the moon.

In terms of a partial explanation of what you are seeing ....   The variables `p` and `q` will probably receive values corresponding to whatever happens to be in memory at the location where they are created - and therefore to whatever some code (within an operating system driver, within your program, even within some other program) happened to write at that location previously.   But that is only one of many possible explanations.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not initialised the variables - the code resorts to undefined behaviour. So anything can happen including what you have experienced.

C++ gives you more than enough rope to hang yourself. Compile with all the warnings switched on to avoid some of the perils.

Comment: Okay, I get it. Just one thing - if I initialise pointers p and q to zero, they point at memory location zero is what it means? as in 0x0?

Comment: It means they point to zero (this is the null pointer). 0x0 is just  a hexadecimal representation of the number zero. You can chose any base to represent numbers - hexadecimal is good for computing as easy to convert to/from binary

Answer (score 0):

When you do not initiate a variable, it set to a random or specific value based on the compiler policy.
About ++ if you create a pointer to class A, and use ++ the pointer will be incremented by sizeof(A).
And about your last question, *p=5 is a good instance of undefined behavior when you did not allocate a memory for p;